# Reversalible function for swapping colours in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that returns an array of colours:

```
default: function () {

    // Get our colours array
    var colours = [service.kits.kit.colour1, service.kits.kit.colour2, service.kits.kit.colour3];

    // If our third colour is blank
    if (!colours[2]) {

        // Is our first or second colour white
        var isWhite = colours[0] === 'ffffff' || colours[1] === 'ffffff';

        // Set our thrid colour
        colours[2] = isWhite ? 'a6a6a6' : 'ffffff';
    }

    // Return our colours
    return colours;
},
```

which I then use like this:

```
// Checks to see what colour was selected for Colour 1 and 2 and sets the 3rd colour
var setSelectedColours = function () {

    // Get our default colours
    var colours = service.colours.default();

    // Apply to our selected colours
    service.colours.selected = angular.copy(colours);
    service.colours.selectedLeisure = angular.copy(colours);
};
```

I have a directive which I use to swap colours, which looks like this:

```
.directive('colourSwapper', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'ColourSwapperController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            // Get to see if we are working with the leisure colours or not
            var leisurewear = attrs.hasOwnProperty('leisurewear');

            // Create our function
            element.bind('click', function (e) {

                // Apply the scope
                scope.$apply(function () {

                    // Use the algorithm for leisurwear items
                    controller.swapColours(leisurewear);
                });

                // Prevent any other actions
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

pretty straight forward so far.
The function for swapping the colours is held in my controller, like this:

```
.controller('ColourSwapperController', ['ConfiguratorService', function (shared) {
    var self = this;

    // Assign our private properties
    var defaultColours = shared.colours.default(),
        tempColour,
        leisureColour = '000e31',
        leisureColours = [leisureColour, '001444'];

    // Used to swap the colours for a garment
    self.swapColours = function (leisurewear) {

        // Get our colours
        var colours = leisurewear ? shared.colours.selectedLeisure : shared.colours.selected;

        // If we are leisurewear and colour 1 and 2 are not navy and we don't have a temp colour
        if (leisurewear && leisureColours.indexOf(defaultColours[0]) === -1 && leisureColours.indexOf(defaultColours[1]) === -1 && !tempColour) {

            // Assign our first colour to our temp colour
            tempColour = colours[0];

            // Make our first colour our 
            colours[0] = leisureColour;

            // If we are playingwear or we have a tempColour
        } else {

            // If we have a tempColour
            if (tempColour) {

                // Set our first colour to our tempColour
                colours[0] = tempColour;

                // Reset our tempColour
                tempColour = null;
            }

            // If our last colour is the hightlight colour and we have not swapped, and our first colour is not the same as our second colour
            if (colours[2] === defaultColours[2] && colours[0] === defaultColours[0] && defaultColours[0] !== defaultColours[1]) {

                // Get colour 1
                var c1 = colours.shift();

                // Move it to the middle
                colours.splice(1, 0, c1);

                // If our last colour is our highlight colour and we have already swapped
            } else if (colours[2] === defaultColours[2]) {

                // Get our highlight colour
                var h1 = colours.pop();

                // Move it to the middle
                colours.splice(1, 0, h1);

                // If our highlight colour is in the middle and our first colour is actually our second colour, and we our first colour is not the same as our second colour
            } else if (colours[1] === defaultColours[2] && colours[0] === defaultColours[1] && defaultColours[0] !== defaultColours[1]) {

                // Get colour 1 and 2
                var c1 = colours.pop();
                var c2 = colours.shift();

                // Swap our colours
                colours.splice(0, 0, c1);
                colours.push(c2);

                // If our hightlight colour is in the middle and our first colour is in the original place, move our hightlight colour back to the last position
            } else if (colours[1] === defaultColours[2]) {

                // If we have a tempColour
                if (tempColour) {

                    // Set our first colour to our tempColour
                    colours[0] = tempColour;

                    // Reset our tempColour
                    tempColour = null;
                }

                // Get colour 2
                var c2 = colours.pop();

                // Insert c2 into the middel
                colours.splice(1, 0, c2);
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

Now, this is a bit more complicated. There are 3 colours, they can be arranged in a way that Colour 3 can only be in position 1 and 2, but Colour 1 and 2 can be in any position.

If the colours are for leisurewear, then the same rule applies **but** another colour is thrown in between each step at position 0 (unless that colour has already been chosen and is in position 1 or 2).

My function works fine, but it is linear in that if a button is pressed, it will always go in one direction. I would "like" it to go in 2 directions, so there is a back and forward button that reverse the function.

Does anyone know how I can do that to my current function?

Comment: I have some problem understanding what you mean. Can you set up a plunker to show the behaviour you are describing?

Answer (score 0):

make an array that stores the colors sequence

```
var colorsOrderSet=[];
```

when you click the button

```
var colorChangeNumber = 0;
```

when it clicks it should store the information in an array

```
colorsOrderSet[colorChangeNumber] = colours;
```

and then increment it by one so that it will store the number

```
colorChangeNumber++;
```

the go back function
will onclick

```
ColorChangeNumber--;
colorsOrderSet[colorChangeNumber] = colours;
```